# Extjs / Javascript - wait for MessageBox response before function return

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, response

I'm working on a project with Extjs, version 4.0.7 and i have a problem.
I have a function which verifies data validity before save. It looks like this:

```
        me.validateEmployeeSystemSettingsOnSave = function (a,b,c) { 
           switch (c) {
        case 1:{
         if(expression)
           return {success: false}
           if(expression2){
           Ext.Msg.show({
                title:'',
                    msg:'',
                buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
                fn: function (btn) {
                if (btn == 'yes') {
                return { success: true };
                }
                else if (btn == 'no') {
                return { success: false};
                }
                },
                modal: true
                 });
             }

      else return {success: true}; /*problem line*/ //this is the default answer, when function will 
//not enter any expression and return {success: true} 

    }
    case 2:{
    }
    }
```

My above function is called in an onSave function like this:

```
 var response = me.validateEmployeeSystemSettingsOnSave(dsa,ssa,daa){
   if(response.success){
this.save();
}
else{
}
}
```

My question is:
Is there any way to wait for the answer of the Ext.msg.show(), before reaching the default `return`, which i marked with /*problem line*/ ? 
Because now the function doesn't take my yes or no answer, it always return `{success: 'true'}`, which is normal, taking into consideration how is the function structured.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: you have displayed message box on else if(expression2), so when message is displayed, else return {success: true}; condition will not executed.

Comment: You are right, i put it by mistake here, but in my code is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should never wait, Use a callback instead!** So in your case execute a callback instead of returning `{ success: true };`